# Menú en Java se queda en un ciclo

Tags: java, netbeans, ciclos

Cuando ingreso la opción 1, debería retornar a crear los datos de un cliente pero se queda en el menú
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor en vez de pantallazos usa la herramienta para bloques de código. Así se lee mejor, es más fácil de copiar y se te ayudará mejor.

Answer (score 1):

reemplaza de la linea 43 a la 47 por esto:

```
menu=Integer.parseInt( JOptionPane.showInputDialog("aqui tu texto del menu"));
```